# how to record screen using ffmpeg with variable framerate

Tags: .net, ffmpeg, video-capture, screen-recording

I want to record desktop using ffmpeg with variable framerate.

set a limit of fps to 120fps
now ffmpeg handle automatically that my max limit is 120
if pc is highly configured then record to 120
otherwise record auto fps like 5,10 whatever

i searched on google i found -vsync 2 and -vsync vfr but these are not working.

my command is

ffmpeg -use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1 -re -vsync vfr -thread_queue_size 1024 -rtbufsize 1024 -indexmem 1024 -probesize 32 -analyzeduration 0 -framerate 120 -f rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb32 -video_size 1366x768 -i \.\pipe\testscreen-4c0b1a88-d4d0-4f6a-55a6-c4587a0ccb7c3 -async 1 -thread_queue_size 1024 -rtbufsize 1024 -indexmem 1024 -probesize 32 -f s16le -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 44100 -ac 2 -i \.\pipe\testscreen-d185c2a9-ac89-4966-b8d7-cec897848790 -fflags +genpts -fflags nobuffer -r 120 -vcodec libx264 -crf 21 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset ultrafast -b:v 0 -maxrate 0 -bf 0 -profile:v high -x264opts "keyint=300:bframes=0:sliced_threads=1:slices=4:lookahead_threads=4:threads=4" -tune zerolatency -movflags +faststart -y -fflags +genpts -c:a aac -strict -2 -b:a 128k "C:\2021-08-16_13-21-38-815.mp4"

Comment: The actual framerate depends on your capture source.

Comment: how do i record screen on variable frame rate ?